# (Corrected in Wikipedia) Every subsemigroup is in its own normalizer

Tags: abstract-algebra, semigroups

Let $G$ be a group and $S \subseteq G$. We define the normalizer of $S$ as $N(S) := \{ n \in G : nS = Sn\}$

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centralizer_and_normalizer);

> If $S$ is a subsemigroup of $G$, then $N(S)$ contains $S$.

But I can't prove it. Everything that $S$ being a **subsemigroup** tells me is that $\forall s \in S,\ sS \subseteq S$ and $Ss \subseteq S$

How would one derive that $\forall s \in S,\ sS = Ss$ ? If S were a **subgroup** or finite, it would be trivial.

Comment: There's a disconnect between your title and wikipedia's claim

Comment: Just edited Wikipedia to correct the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not true. Consider the free group generated by two symbols $a,b$. Let $A$ be its subsemigroup generated by $a,b$. Now $a\in A$, but $aA$ consists of all strings in $a,b$ starting with $a$, while $Aa$ consists of all strings in $a,b$ terminating with $a$. They are obviously different.